# Step by step procedure to obtain irreducible representations and  construct character table of a group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am studying group theory and character table of $S_2$ is given in the book.
But how to obtain this table is not given.

Can someone explain how exactly to construct this table?

Comment: Once you have finished the book, you'll be able to fill in such tables yourself. And for S2, it will take like 30 seconds.

Comment: @Pratik: Your accounts will be merged soon; unfortunately there seems to be an issue that the SE developers have to deal with first though.

Answer (score 4):

S<sub>2</sub> is a group with two elements, call them 1 and *t*.  A representation of S<sub>2</sub> takes 1 to the identity matrix and *t* to some matrix, so we can think of representations *X* of S<sub>2</sub> as simply some matrix *X*(*t*).  Of course not just any matrix will do, since *X* is a homomorphism and so $(X(t))^2 = X(t^2) = X(1)$ has to be the identity matrix.  In other words, *X*(*t*) has to be a matrix whose square is the identity.  All of its eigenvalues also have to square to the identity, so they are all ±1.  By considering the Jordan canonical form of *X*(*t*), you can see that *X*(*t*) must be diagonalizable (since a large Jordan block does not square to the identity).

Of course if we diagonalize *X*(*t*), then each of the standard subspaces is an invariant subspace, so *X* is only irreducible if it is one dimensional.

However, there are not very many 1×1 matrices whose eigenvalues are just ±1.  They are *X*<sub>1</sub>(*t*) = [1] and *X*<sub>2</sub>(*t*) = [-1].  These are both irreducible representations of S<sub>2</sub>, so we have found them all.  Writing down their traces we get:

$$\begin{array}{r|rr}
S_2 & 1 & t \\ \hline X_1 & 1 & 1 \\ X_2 & 1 & -1 \end{array}$$

Similar ideas work for any finite abelian group.  One takes a minimal generating set and arbitrarily assigns appropriate roots of unity to the generators, giving one one-dimensional irreducible representation per element of the group.